# TypeError: unbound method player_init() must be called with Player instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

Tags: python, typeerror

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

width, height = 1000, 700
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.pos_x = x
        self.pos_y = y
        self.width, height = 1000, 700
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

    def player_init(self):
        sprite = pygame.image.load("Character Sprite.png")
        self.window.blit(sprite, (self.pos_x, self.pos_y))

while 1:
    Player.player_init(500-38, 350-49)
```

I've been looking around a little but I can't seem to find an answer to why this type error

> TypeError: unbound method `player_init()` must be called with `Player` instance as first argument (got `int` instance instead)

keeps popping up whenever I create a class.

Comment: `player_init()` only takes a single argument `self`. Try `Player(500-38, 350-49).player_init()` .

Comment: Note: Remove `while 1` unless you want your code to hang and loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `Player(x, y).player_init()` because `player_init` also requires the `self` argument which also uses variables specified in `__init__`. You are also calling `player_init` with 2 arguments but it only accepts one.

Answer (score 0):

First (before `while`) create instance of class `Player` with expected arguments

```
player = Player(500-38, 350-49)
```

and later use it (but without arguments)

```
player.player_init()
```

---

But for me your code should look like this

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WIDTH  = 1000
HEIGHT = 700

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class Player:
               # <- empty line to make code more readable
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Character Sprite.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

# empty

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# - objects -

player = Player(500-38, 350-49)

# - mainloop -

while True:

    # other code

    player.draw(window)
```

`self.rect` is very usefull to set position ie. `self.rect.center` and it has functions to check collisions. `player.rect.collidrect(enemy.rect)` or `player.rect.collidpoint(mouse_pos)`

Usefull class `pygame.spripte.Group()` expects `self.rect` and `self.image` to automatically draw all sprites.

Answer (score 0):

```html
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 700

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class Player:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Character Sprite.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

# empty

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()

# - objects -

player = Player(500-38, 350-49)
player.draw(pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT)))

# - mainloop -


while True:
    # other code
    pygame.display.flip() # add to out image from display
```